# Pass Page Name to function (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a routine which finds all the controls on a page, which I then apply some changes to.
The routine works quite well but I will have to add the chunk of code to every master page and content page to get my results.

I would like to create a single sub routine (which will be in a module) which when called from each page will carry out the work. The only thing I think I need to do to do to make this work is to be able to pass the page name the controls are on to the sub routine to run my routine and have the module  make the changes I require to the page I pass to it.

I am sure this is an easy process, but for the life of me I can’t work it out. Can someone help me on how to pass the page name so the routine will apply the changes to that page?
I am using asp.net in Visual Studio 2010, and the code behind is vb.net.

My routine is written in the code behind, not java or aspx. I don’t care if the answer is in C# or vb.net as I can convert if required.
Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can send this.Page.UniqueID value as a parameter to the subroutine when you call it from the module.

Comment: It gives the current page where you call the subroutine from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current page's class name use:

```
this.GetType().Name;
```

---

If your page inherits from another page, you would use:

```
this.GetType().BaseType.Name;
```

---

What I would do is create a base page that all your pages inherit from and put your `FindAllControls()` method there.

Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
using System.Web.UI;

public abstract class BasePage : Page
{
    public void FindAllControls()
    {
        var currentClassName = this.GetType().BaseType.Name;

        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Then, for example, if you had a Login page, it would look like this:

```
using System;

public partial class Login : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FindAllControls();
    }
}
```